# kotlin/android - null custom attribute

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm reading [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#addprop) to create my own custom button. `soundFile` is always null. What have I missed?

res/values/attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SoundButton">
        <attr name="soundFile" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.arniesoundboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.arniesoundboard.SoundButton
        android:text="stop it"
        custom:soundFile="stop_it.mp3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

com.arniesoundboard.SoundBoard

```
class SoundButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton(context, attrs) {

    private var soundFile: String?

    init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SoundButton, 0, 0).apply {
            soundFile = getString(R.styleable.SoundButton_soundFile)
            recycle()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why docs refer to [your_package_name].

Replace

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.arniesoundboard"
```

With

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```